# Removed all installed packages and I cant boot from any other device (usb or dvd)

Tags: boot, usb, 17.10, dvd

so today I removed all installed packages on my laptop by mistake. I was able to get into console in recovery mode and backup my important data. I wanted to make complete reinstall, but i cant boot from my USB flash disk (I tried 3 of those, I was able to boot from them on other machine) or from DVD. If I plug in flash disk or DVD i get stuck on "logo" of my laptop. I tried almost everything, changing settings in bios, without any luck. Before I installed Ubuntu I was able to boot from USB. (I had few OS installed before)
Laptop is Lenovo z50-70 (i7 version).

Comment: I almost remember something about z50s having the bios get corrupted from the install process for ubuntu. Someone should confirm here, but this might (maybe) require Lenovo to do some warranty work if you aren't able to flash a new bios yourself through jtag or another system.

Comment: I was too scared to flash bios, so after some thinking I unscrew HDD. Then I was able to boot from DVD after error message "ubuntu cant boot" or something like this. Once I boot up I plugged back in HDD a started "reinstall". Now I am nervously waiting for result.

Comment: Pray tell, is this a bios or uefi system? If uefi, the boot order can get changed by the OS so that could have been the root cause of the issue.

Comment: So reinstall failed, I dont know why I went for fresh and it works.. so i guess problem solved. 
It was installed on UEFI.